# Writing To NSStream Relying on hasSpaceAvailable method or Delegate Event NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable

Tags: ios, nsstream, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream

While writing onto `NSStream` Should i Rely on

'`hasSpaceAvailable`' method or the event in the 'handle:event' method

'`NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`'

Or Should i check '`hasSpaceAvailable`' if not available, i have to retry after a particular 
amount of time or should i wait till the delegate event to call till i begin to write?

As of now its working when i use hasSpaceAvailable and retry after some time dont know if its
the right practice.

Any Help would be of much great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're about to send first piece of data use `hasSpaceAvailable` to determine whether stream is ready.

After sending some data you'll be getting `stream:handleEvent:` method called and there you should check if `NSStreamEvent` var is equal to `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`; then you can write more data to the stream, otherwise something is wrong or stream is full.

Comment: So for the very first time i must use hasSpaceAvailable then on i can rely on the delegates itself?

Comment: Yeah. I've done that in my project some time ago and it worked fine.